# Color code stores based off given criteria

Tags: powerbi, data-analysis, background-color, measure

I have a table with the shortage numbers for 20,000 stores from 2020 – Present. I’d like to color code the top 200 stores with the highest shortage for each division(1-10) from 2020 – 2023 in red and the top for 2023 in Orange. The rest of the stores should show as normal.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you please share your input and expected output? Your columns ? The rules ? The visuals ?

Comment: Yes, this can be done with a DAX field measure. We could give you some sample code if you added more details to your question as Amira requested.